# How to break down a product id and quantity string from paypal ipn

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, paypal, paypal-ipn

Heys guys,

I'm having a bit of a headache with this one. The Paypal Ipn sends back a string of products ordered with quantities and that gets stored in an orders table of the database like so 1-3,2-2,4-3
This interpreted is as so - productid is 1 and quantity of 3, productid of 2 and quantity of 2 etc.
I am having an extremely hard time splitting all of these numbers and delimiters up so that i can display the products ordered and their quantities in a backend admin panel when I click to view that specific order.
Can someone please share their wisdom with me and help on this I don't even know where to start honestly! Even if I explode it to an array, I still can figure out how to choose the product id's from sql query etc! please help!!! Please see below:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id=$order_id";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$products_ordered = $row['product_id_array'];
```

when I echo $products_ordered, I get 1-3,2-2,4-3

How do I then get this information from the products table?

Comment: is `$products_ordered` a string or array?

Comment: Hi! It's a string

Comment: Seems like you keeping track of ordered_items in the same table as orders. My recommendation is to create one table "orders" with date, customer info, payment info, and another table "ordered_items" that has one row for every item in the order. Each of those rows should reference the order_id. One of the issues with the way you are doing it is that you have to process that string every single time you want to display the data. Instead of just when you do the insert. Also you can use the explode function to turn the string into an array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following function to split your order string into an array:

```
function explodeOrders($orders) {
    $orders = explode(",", $orders); // Explodes your string, separating by each order

    foreach($orders as $key => $order) {
        $orders[$key] = explode("-", $order); // Explodes your order into an array separating the id and the count
    }

    return $orders;
}
```

Then, executing something like:

```
var_dump(json_encode(explodeOrders("1-3,2-2,4-3"), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

will output something like:

```
[
    [
        "1",
        "3"
    ],
    [
        "2",
        "2"
    ],
    [
        "4",
        "3"
    ]
]
```

That said, your `orders` database isn't organized very well. If you can change it, I recommend separating your orders and their quantities into a different table somehow, rather than storing it as a string. If you can't, though, this should do.

Comment: Thanks mate. How would i then query this from the database

Comment: Does the code you posted above not work? Just use that and then pass `$products_ordered` to the function. i.e. `$products_ordered_array = explodeOrders($products_ordered);`